# Javascript: return long CR-delimited list as variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, text-files

I'm trying to take a long ~500k text file that just contains strings separated by newline characters, and dump it into a JS array:

```
hello
world
blah
blah
```

Due to the hassle of reading a local text file in JS, I thought I might first dump the contents of this text file into a JS file, and maybe return all that text via a simple function, so I can parse the list of strings as an array. If it were a comma-delimited list of strings, it would be easy. But it's a CR/newline delimited list.

Is there a better way to convert a long CR/newline-delimited list of strings from a TEXT file to a JS Array? Thanks.

Comment: @sebasaenz I can copy/paste the text at design-time. It's a static text file, so that's not the issue.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: @guest271314: The issue is I'm trying to load the contents of a text file into an array in another JS file. Please re-read the original question.

Comment: Are you trying to create a new `.js` file having contents of `.txt` file as array value of a variable assignment? Or concatenate array as variable assignment value as an existing `.js` file? That is, an existing `javascript` array? Can you include `javascript` file contents that you are trying to concatenate contents within at Question and what you have tried to achieve requirement?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

Split on the line endings:

```
var list = text.split(/[\r\n]+/);
```

As for dumping it into a JS file, that isn't necessary so long as the file is on the same server (domain name) as the page. You could use AJAX to load the file as a string and process it from there.

Comment: I had a lot of trouble using ajax to get the file contents (I'm just running this on the local machine). So in your example above, I don't know how to dump the long list of strings into the `text` variable. I'm trying this: return 'hello world blah blah'; The single quote-like things don't seem to work.

Comment: @TheDudeDude Development should be done in conjunction with a web server, local or otherwise. AJAX (and other things) don't play well with `FILE:` due to modern browser security features. If the text has quotes in it then just wrapping it in quotes won't work. If you can wrap your text in quotes, you may be better off with `window.text = 'text';`.

Comment: Solved: since I'm able to make this work at design-time (ajax just isn't relevant here), I just used notepad++ to replace all the linebreaks (\r\n) with pipes for the entire huge text file. I then used Visual Studio Code to copy the modified text file into a JS file, and wrapped it all in a JS function that returns an array (using split()). The function works fine in my code now. Thanks for the suggestions.